# How to write an XSLT to replace a subtree by two or more subtrees resulting from the splitting of the original one?

Tags: xslt

I have a timed sentence-by-sentence XML representation of speech.

```
<speech>
    <sentence start="23.56" end="24.67">blah blah... blah</sentence>
    ...
</speech>
```

Although there is more structure inside the sentences, it is trivial to write an XSLT to select the desired info to obtain a plain version like

```
23.56 24.67 blah blah... blah
...
```

The difficulty arises when there is a timestamp element inside a sentence

```
    <sentence start="23.56" end="24.67">blah blah... <ts t="24.01"/> blah blah... </sentence>
```

and the desired output is the sentence split:

```
23.56 24.01 blah blah... blah
24.01 24.67 blah blah... blah
```

In my short understanding of XSLTs, a "sentence" including one or more "ts" is a subtree that I need to replace by two or more "sentence" subtrees after splitting and grouping the children according to the "ts" element, so after that, the plain version would be obtained in the "trivial" way (but maybe a different approach could be better/easier)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Editing to clarify...**

From the simplest input

```
<speech>
    <sentence start="23.56" end="24.67">Sed ut perspiciatis, <ts t="24.01"/> unde omnis iste natus error</sentence>
</speech>
```

I am trying to obtain the plain text output

```
23.56 24.01 Sed ut perspiciatis, 
24.01 24.67 unde omnis iste natus error
```

My comment about transforming the tree was about seeing the problem as a first step going to

```
<speech>
    <sentence start="23.56" end="24.01">Sed ut perspiciatis,</sentence>
    <sentence start="24.01" end="24.67">unde omnis iste natus error</sentence>
</speech>
```

followed by a trivial conversión to the desired output.

Comment: Show us your trivial attempt then if you say you have one. In both of your input samples each `sentence` element contais child nodes so could be regarded a subtree. If you want to group child nodes "according" to `ts` elements then see the grouping section https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info. It also always helps if you state the version and or processor you are using for XSLT and show the exact grouping results in terms of XML.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I will carefully study the reference you send me.

Comment: The logic that needs to be applied here is not clear at all. Please explain the required action in words, and don't use an ambiguous example: you have 2 identical text nodes and it's anyone's guess which one ended up where in the output.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I am going to edit the question to show an input-output example.

Comment: Continuing with my response to Martin:
When I talk about trivial processing I mean that if not for the "ts" elements, it is easy to generate the desired raw output by processing the rest of the elements that I have hidden for the sake of simplicity. When I pose the tree transformation, I do it as an intermediate structural solution to convert the problem into the trivial case in which there are no "ts" elements.
Regarding the version of XSLTs, I have only used 1.0 (Xalan transformer from Java) but I see that I could use 3.0 (Saxon-HE 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the fragments up in XSLT 2 or 3 with

```
  <xsl:template match="sentence">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="ts">
          <sentence>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::ts)]"/>
          </sentence>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

The computation of the start and end attributes is missing above, I have not quite understood it from the example, perhaps

```
  <xsl:template match="sentence">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="ts">
          <sentence 
              start="{let $pos := position()
                      return
                      if ($pos eq 1)
                      then ../@start 
                      else ../ts[$pos - 1]/@t}" 
                     end="{if (current-group()[last()] instance of element(ts)) then current-group()[last()]/@t else ../@end}">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(self::ts)]"/>
          </sentence>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
```

does it right.

Comment: Thank you Martin!. I will try it as soon as possible using Saxon-HE.
Although I do not know XSLT in such depth, I see the logic and it sounds great to me. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Checked: it works terrific, Martin!. Thanks for everything!